# Crop and rotate picture OpenCV

Tags: opencv, rotation, crop

I am new in OpenCV so please to be lenient.
I am doing an Android application to recognize the squares/rectangles and crop them.  Function which looks for the squares/rectangles puts the found objects to vector> squares. I just wonder how to crop the picture according to the data in points stored in vector> squares and how to compute an angle on which the picture should be rotated. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

This post is citing from [OpenCV QA: Extract a RotatedRect area](http://answers.opencv.org/question/497/extract-a-rotatedrect-area/).

There's a great article by [Felix Abecassis](http://felix.abecassis.me) on rotating and deskewing images. This also shows you how to extract the data in the RotatedRect:

- http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/

You basically only need [cv::getRotationMatrix2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrotationmatrix2d) to get the rotation matrix for the affine transformation with [cv::warpAffine](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine) and [cv::getRectSubPix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrectsubpix) to crop the rotated image. The relevant lines in my application are:

```cpp
// This is the RotatedRect, I got it from a contour for example...
RotatedRect rect = ...;
// matrices we'll use
Mat M, rotated, cropped;
// get angle and size from the bounding box
float angle = rect.angle;
Size rect_size = rect.size;
// thanks to http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/
if (rect.angle < -45.) {
    angle += 90.0;
    swap(rect_size.width, rect_size.height);
}
// get the rotation matrix
M = getRotationMatrix2D(rect.center, angle, 1.0);
// perform the affine transformation on your image in src,
// the result is the rotated image in rotated. I am doing
// cubic interpolation here
warpAffine(src, rotated, M, src.size(), INTER_CUBIC);
// crop the resulting image, which is then given in cropped
getRectSubPix(rotated, rect_size, rect.center, cropped);
```

Comment: Although the answer is almost valid, This rotates your *entire* image before cropping. *Highly* expensive operation there.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of useful posts around, I'm sure you can do a better search.

Crop:

- [cropping IplImage most effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587204/176769)

Rotate:

- [OpenCV: how to rotate IplImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289690/opencv-how-to-rotate-iplimage)
- [Rotating or Resizing an Image in OpenCV](http://www.shervinemami.info/imageTransforms.html)

Compute angle:

- [OpenCV - Bounding Box & Skew Angle](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-bounding-box-skew-angle/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756505/croping-an-image-in-ios-uisng-opencv-face-detect I am facing cropping problem in iphone live video stream.. Could you please have a look at my post..

Answer (score 0):

Altought this question is quite old, I think there is the need for an answer that is not expensive as rotating the whole image (see @bytefish's answer). You will need a bounding rect, *for some reason `rotatedRect.boundingRect()` didn't work for me*, so I had to use `Imgproc.boundingRect(contour)`. This is OpenCV for Android, the operations are almost the same for other environments:

```
Rect roi = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);
// we only work with a submat, not the whole image:
Mat mat = image.submat(roi); 
RotatedRect rotatedRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray()));
Mat rot = Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(rotatedRect.center, rotatedRect.angle, 1.0);
// rotate using the center of the roi
double[] rot_0_2 = rot.get(0, 2);
for (int i = 0; i < rot_0_2.length; i++) {
    rot_0_2[i] += rotatedRect.size.width / 2 - rotatedRect.center.x;
}
rot.put(0, 2, rot_0_2);
double[] rot_1_2 = rot.get(1, 2);
for (int i = 0; i < rot_1_2.length; i++) {
    rot_1_2[i] += rotatedRect.size.height / 2 - rotatedRect.center.y;
}
rot.put(1, 2, rot_1_2);
// final rotated and cropped image:
Mat rotated = new Mat();
Imgproc.warpAffine(mat, rotated, rot, rotatedRect.size);
```